# Algorithm for assigning people based on multiple criteria

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a list of users which need to be sorted into committees. The users can rank committees based on their particular preference, but must choose at least one to join. When they have all made their selections, the algorithm should sort them as evenly as possible taking into account their committee preference, gender, age, time zone and country (for now). I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317213/sorting-people-into-groups-based-on-votes) and its answer would seem like a good choice, but it is unclear to me how to add the various constraints to the algorithm for it to work.

Would anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this, please?

Comment: Can you give a small example of a few people to be contributed, and the final, desired result for such a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for "clustering" will get you nowhere, because this is not a clustering type if task.

Instead, this is an assignment problem.

For further informarion, see:

- Knapsack Problem
- [Generalized Assignment Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem)

Usually, these are NP-hard to solve. Thus, one will usually choose a greedy optimization heuristic to find a reasonably good solution faster.

Think about how to *best* assign one person at a time.

Then, process the data as follows:

1. assign everybody that can only be assigned in a single way
2. find an unassigned person that is *hard* to assign, stop if everybody is assigned
3. assign the best possible way
4. remove preferences that are no longer admissible, and go to 1 again (there may be new person with only a single choice left)

For bonus points, add a source of randomness, and an overall quality measure. Then run the algorothm 10 times, and keep only the best result.
For further bonus, add an postprocessing optimization: when can you transfer one person to another group or swap to persons to improve the overall quality? Iterate over all persons to find such small improvements until you cannot find any.