# Sort people to groups (similar to min cost flow network)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, design-patterns

Im having trouble with sorting people in to groups.

What I have to do is sort people (around 100) to groups (8 groups).
Each user has his preferred groups ranked from 1 - 6.

I need to sort them with the best possible outcome for each day of the week (monday to friday - 5 different arrangements).

User should never be in the same group twice but it can be in group that is not on his "preferred" list (if other outcome is not possible)

Similar problem is described here: [Sorting People into Groups based on Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317213/sorting-people-into-groups-based-on-votes)
but I don't know which library should i use for my project and how to make 5 different groups.

I'm using node (javascript).

EDIT: There should be (roughly) the same number of users in each group (number of users divided by number of groups).

Comment: Define "best possible outcome".  Are there size restrictions on groups?

Comment: the best outcome is that each user is sorted in to groups that he ranked from 1 - 5. There should be (roughly) the same number of users in each group